# How to make checkboxes more obvious

Tags: interaction-design, checkboxes

I have a few checkboxes on a page which are checked by default. The users do have a choice to uncheck them if they like.

However, in our user research so far, the users seem to have missed the fact that there are checkboxes on the page that they could uncheck. Is there a way to make this more obvious for the user?

The checkboxes could possibly not be 'above the fold', and the user might need to scroll down to see them. This would always happen on a mobile screen.

I have attached a mockup of the page for a better understanding:

[image]

Comment: Its hard to help you improve without seeing the actual layout. 
Could you maybe provide the real version? Its important to see the big picture regarding font sizes, colors, whitespace and so on.

Of course you can censor the stuff you don't want us to see.

Comment: Can you add a bit more context? What's the reason people come to the page? Are the checkboxes related to the content?

Comment: It's hard to say anything from you wireframe, since the checkboxes really stand out on it. So we really need to see a bit more, like colors and images, so we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them larger. As tiny as they are, and as thin as the checkmark itself is, I can see them being interpreted as bullets.

Depending on the style of your site's buttons, you might want to redesign them to better match that style, so the user better understands they are clickable elements. For instance, if your site buttons have rounded corners, redesign the checkbox controls to have rounded corners as well.

Recommendations:

- Increase size of the checkbox control
- Increase the weight of the checkmark itself to make it more obvious
- Restyle control to match other site controls

Answer (score 0):

Use bigger checkboxes or the alternative [Switch control](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/switch/preferences).

Comment: That was my initial idea, but it looks like its not the most familiar UI for people using a desktop browser. On mobile, the switch control is perfectly intuitive for most users.